# Android Update Results in "Hash of data does not match digest in descriptor" error

Tags: updates, downloading, device-firmware

My Samsung Galaxy A70 prompted for a software update this morning. I dutifully complied and left it to get on with it.

Upon return, I was presented with the following error:

> partition tz
>
> Reason tz: Hash of data does not match digest in descriptor.2nd

Plus some other stuff about hash, firmware version, etc.

[image]

To clarify, all I did was select to update. I didn't plug any cables in (as the image indicates), and I wasn't trying any manual firmware/software install.

It's still under warranty, so I'll probably just be taking back to the retailer, but I thought i'd ask here in the hope that there's a quick fix that won't invalidate the warranty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: shame on samsung hope you got all your data in cloud

Comment: Fortunately, yes. Tempted to flash it with odin as there are suggestions this might work.

Comment: Partition TZ sounds like TrustZone; Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) on ARM processors. Vendors keep the pre-kernel boot stages completely closed-source. So I don't think there would be any documented support related to the issue.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thank. So does this support an assumption that this is an issue closer related to hardware?

Comment: @JamesWiseman "closed-source" software component is a more probable assumption. It's not about Android OS but totally related to SoC, bootloaders etc. So you can say related to hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise this isn't maybe the most helpful of answers, but I thought I'd post it anyway in case someone else finds it useful.

The phone was under warranty, so took it to the local Samsung store. The support assistants commented that they'd "never seen this error before". It went in for repair and emerged fully working again.

When I asked what the problem one, I got a vague "they replaced some hardware component".

Again, not the most helpful, but enough to say that it looks like something beyond the help of a software re-install.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and Odin firmware flash did the trick.

For the next unlucky soul to stumble on this thread for help I'll add some more info.
Download Odin - https://samsungodin.com/how-to-use-odin/
Download Firmware - https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/ - make sure to download the files for you phone and more specifically your carrier!
For some reason Samgsung.com doesn't have the firmware for the S10+ and I didn't check other phones. Sammobile allows you to get the files for free but they have add timers on the download links. You need to turn off adblock otherwise you will never see the download link pop up. Took me like 20 minutes to figure this out. I can't vouch for this site but there's a very angry commenter on the how to page so at least he believes in it.
If you arrived at the error the same way I did you will then want to update you phone from the Samsung Switch application. I received a shitty refurb to replace my original that bricked so I've had to only update from this application. (Thanks Samsung/Verizon)
Smart Switch - https://www.samsung.com/us/smart-switch/
You plug in your phone after turning on this app and it will prompt to update. Idk if this application can fail like the normal downloading over the network but its got me past two update errors now.